# Changing color of the row while comparing the dates

Tags: angular, firebase

I am using firebase and angular2. In the firebase, I am saving user informations: Name, Paid Date and Due Date. 
   My html file looks like below:

```
    <div> <label>Today's date:</label> {{todaysdate'}}</div>
      <ul *ngFor="let member of members" class="collection">
      <li class="collection-item" item-width="100%">
        <label>NAME:</label>{{member.name}} 
        <label>Paid Date:</label>{{member.paiddate}}
        <label> Due Date:</label>{{member.duedate}}
      </li>
      </ul>
```

What I wanted to do is, change the color of every row whose `duedate >= todaysdate`. Would anybody suggest me or refer to correct link I should be following?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create a custom css class like:

```
.redBackground {
    background-color:red
}
```

and then bind an expression to it with angular

```
<li [class.redBackground]="duedate >= todaysdate">
```

Comment: also I haven't tested this recently, but I just remembered at one point there was a bug with the ordering of class & a conditional class.  make sure you include your standard class before any conditional ones <li class="collection-item" [class.redBackground]="duedate >= todaysdate">

Comment: Is there a way, I can sort the list with duedate or the ones with the red background at the top, without using pipes?